# How can I determine what fonts are used by an mxd?

Tags: arcmap

A client has sent me an mxd and a file gdb.

When I look at the symbols, they don't look good.  I think they need to send me some fonts.  Is there some way I can use arcmap to determine the name of the font file I need so that I can request it from them?

Comment: This has been a issue for years - in reverse too with the default ESRI TTF fonts and exporting a map with text to PDF. Your client should know the font used - they must provide it for you to view the symbols correctly. Identifying the font via the mxd is unlikely - maybe via python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look at a few ArcGIS 10 mxds suggests that grepping

```
[A-Za-z0-9 ]+ÿÿ×â
```

will turn up (loads of) font names.  I used [Windows Grep](http://www.wingrep.com/) for this test.  I can't guarantee it will turn up *all* the font names, but the approach looks promising.

Here's a screen shot of the output.  Note how two font names were picked up ("Batang" at the end of line 81), not just the default "Arial" that litters the file.

[image]