# Why are the special fonts in a .mxd-project not used/found?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, arcgis-engine, mxd

I have a .mxd-project file from a customer which uses special fonts (TrueType). I installed these fonts in Windows but my application (mostly a MapControl) doesn't use these fonts for displaying. I checked the mxd file (see whuber did [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11126/4167)) in a text editor and the font names do appear.

I didn't find anything about using uncommon fonts in projects. I assume that it should work with simply installing the fonts in the OS but maybe there is something different to do?

What do I have to do to get the fonts displayed in my MapControl?